# AM/PM timeline in amCharts

Tags: amcharts4

I'm having an issue changing the timeline to show 12 hour time with AM/PM instead of 24 hour time.

Adding this line to the timeline chart correctly changes the tooltip to display in AM/PM format:

```
dateAxis.tooltipDateFormat = "hh:mm a";
```

According to the documentation adding this line should do the same for the timeline along the X-axis:

```
dateAxis.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a";
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/ChopperDave/pen/dyoyyZo?editable=true)'s the example I'm using to test.

It isn't working however and there don't seem to be any examples of this working that I can find.

Is this feature not yet working in v4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the date format directly on the dateAxis' `dateFormats` object as documented [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Setting_date_formats), e.g.:

```
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey('hour', 'hh:mm a');
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/05c77b1054ce8b3bdab9d0ca81aa799e?editors=0010)